# Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have a problem. I am having this error when I try to run on debug my springboot application but I have the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.app.myapp.MyappApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

My `MyappApplication` class have the following

```
package com.app.myapp;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.app.myapp.model.Reponse;
import com.app.myapp.service.MyModel;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyappApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements 
CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
ServletContext context;

@Autowired private MyModel myModel;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext acx=SpringApplication.run(MyappApplication.class, args);
    String fileSeparator = File.separator;

}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    
}
   /*
   @Bean
   public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
      return new RestTemplate();
   }*/
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
            TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
 
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                            .build();
 
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
 
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                            .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                            .build();
 
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
                            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
 
            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
            return restTemplate;
    }      
 }
```

My POM is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.app.myapp</groupId>
   <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
  <name>myApp</name>
  <description>Building software</description>
   <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <!--           <scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <!--           <scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
     <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Tried to run your project on my pc. Working correctly.

Comment: @AvijitBarua an invalidate cache and restart solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

My problem was solved by just invalidating the caches and restarting my IDE

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

only Invalidating cache did not help for me. Please once check the scope for your tomcat in pom.xml. Sometimes scope is "provided" and that's why it doesn't compile the class and throws this error:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

If you are commenting any scope here, make sure you restart the system and if needed invalidate cache too for indexes. This worked for me.

Comment: This did it for me, thanks! The project worked fine on my trial version of IntelliJ Ultimate, but wouldn't work on the Community Edition, do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I tried both the solutions available on this post: invalidating cache and removed the scope of the dependency.

After I removed the scope ("provided") it worked for me.

Please don't forget to reload Maven projects after removing the scope.

[image]